# storing bitmap in database. Whats wrong?

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap

here is my database columns: you see that in the last column i put BLOB.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY,PASSWORD TEXT,FNAME TEXT,SNAME TEXT,BIRTHDATE TEXT,MATHGROUP TEXT,GENDER TEXT, PROFILEIMAGE BLOB)");
}
```

i asked from user to choose an image from gallery.
the image is saved in a bitmap.  i have Bitmap bitmap.
when i want to insert the data, i need to convert bitmap to byte []. so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
                        byte [] buffer = stream1.toByteArray();
```

and I insert the data. (the method is defined in the DatabaseHelper class).

```
   boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editID.getText().toString(),
                                editPASSWORD.getText().toString(),
                                editFNAME.getText().toString(),
                                editSNAME.getText().toString(),
                                datePickerBIRTHDATE.getDayOfMonth() + "." + datePickerBIRTHDATE.getMonth() + "." + datePickerBIRTHDATE.getYear(),
                                spinnerMATHGROUP.getSelectedItem().toString(), spinnerGENDER.getSelectedItem().toString(), buffer );
```

i succeed to insert that. so the first user is sigen-up now. but i cant do more now. if the user enters ID and pass, and i start to check a match with his details to data details, the app fails (goes out with note)! i dont have access to database information. 
The problem is for sure with the BLOB column (or what i put in it that makes the database crash). I assume that because when I remove that column, i have no problem with login. 
whats wrong with the code?

**Here is Logcat**

```
    18:49:20 Gradle sync started
18:49:36 Gradle sync completed
18:49:38 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
18:50:23 Gradle build finished in 44s 138ms
18:51:12 Throwable
         Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
         Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 31,4,main] 1159879404
         ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
         SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.3#AI-141.2178183, eap:false,6,main] 393216142
18:52:23 Throwable
         Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
         Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 31,4,main] 1159879404
         ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
         SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.3#AI-141.2178183, eap:false,6,main] 393216142
19:02:29 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:02:35 Gradle build finished with 8 error(s) in 5s 814ms
19:03:41 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:04:41 Gradle build finished in 59s 960ms
19:06:09 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:06:11 Gradle build finished in 2s 559ms
19:08:10 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:08:13 Gradle build finished in 3s 234ms
19:09:07 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:09:10 Gradle build finished in 2s 520ms
19:11:03 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:11:06 Gradle build finished in 2s 985ms
19:12:42 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:12:44 Gradle build finished in 2s 67ms
19:15:39 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:15:49 Gradle build finished in 10s 219ms
19:17:32 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:17:41 Gradle build finished in 9s 521ms
19:18:14 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:18:24 Gradle build finished in 9s 752ms
19:20:13 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
19:20:23 Gradle build finished in 9s 445ms
20:02:46 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:02:56 Gradle build finished in 10s 187ms
20:04:06 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:04:17 Gradle build finished in 11s 160ms
20:04:45 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:05:01 Gradle build finished in 15s 963ms
20:05:14 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:05:24 Gradle build finished in 9s 832ms
20:06:17 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:06:19 Gradle build finished in 2s 449ms
20:06:53 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:06:56 Gradle build finished in 3s 202ms
20:09:25 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
20:09:28 Gradle build finished in 2s 552ms
```

Comment: `the app fails` - Is there a stack trace?

Comment: i am kinda new with programing so i dont know how to show the log file and the stack trace as well. show me how please

Comment: Are you using Android studio? To get to the Logcat (to see your stack trace/see what has gone wrong) click Debug. This window shows threads and variables in the Debugger tab, the device status in the Console tab, and the system log in the Logcat tab.

Comment: ok i added the logcat to the question. i dont know if it helps...